# How to get Hansen forest loss chart to only show values between 2015 and 2020

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I am trying to use ui.Chart.array.values in GEE to make a yearly forest loss chart with the Hansen dataset. I am only interested in the years between 2015 and 2020 and can't figure out how to isolate these years.

```
var lossImage = gfc2020.select(['loss']);
var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var lossYear = gfc2020.select(['lossyear']);
var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1
    }),
  geometry: nps,
  scale: 30, 
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(lossByYear);

var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el){
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format('20%02d'),d.get('sum')];
  });
var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());
print(statsDictionary);

var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: statsDictionary.values(),
  axis: 0,
  xLabels: statsDictionary.keys()
}).setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Yearly Forest Loss',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '####'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Area (square meters)'},
    legend: {position: "none"},
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3
  });
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a bunch of ways you can approach this, but an easy way is to filter the dictionary or select the keys (years) you are interested in:

```
var filterDict = statsDictionary.select(['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'])
print(filterDict, 'filterDict')
```

And then use that dictionary for plotting